# 'linmath.h': Rotation after translation problem

Tags: c, opengl

Using ['linmath.h'](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h), I'm trying to rotate an image after a translation. However, after the translation, the image doesn't move at all.

In the vextex shader, I have

```
gl_Position = transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
```

and in the program, I have

```
mat4x4 transform;
mat4x4_identity(transform);
mat4x4_rotate(transform, transform, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, (float) glfwGetTime());
mat4x4_translate(transform, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
```

I want to point out that translating an image after a rotation (i.e., swapping the last two lines) works fine, so I don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a peek at the [source for `mat4x4_translate`](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/05387571f57224f8cbc2b390b423dab6b9158988/linmath.h#L185-L191), you can see it resets the matrix to identity first.

You might be looking for the next function, [`mat4x4_translate_in_place`](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/05387571f57224f8cbc2b390b423dab6b9158988/linmath.h#L192-L201).